# Select a column value that related to another column min value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| group_id | product_id |  product_name  | price | stock |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  1       |   101      |  Product 1     |  120  |  200  |
----------------------------------------------------------
|  1       |   102      |  Product 2     |  140  |  90   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  1       |   103      |  Product 3     |   90  |  300  | 
-----------------------------------------------------------
|  2       |   104      |  Product 4     |   30  |  45   | 
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to get the product_name that is related to minimum stock, the total price of three products and the minimum stock quantity.

I have tried with,

```
SELECT product_name, sum(price) as total_price, min(stock) as min_stock from tables where group_id = 1 group by group_id
```

It returns following

```
------------------------------------------------
|   product_name    | total_price | min_stock |
------------------------------------------------
|   Product 1       |   350       |   90      |
------------------------------------------------
```

Total Price and Minimum stock is okay, But I need also product_name based on the minimum stock.

So, my expected output is:

```
------------------------------------------------
|   product_name    | total_price | min_stock |
------------------------------------------------
|   Product 2       |   350       |   90      |
------------------------------------------------
```

Please note, the stock column is a calculated value, for example

```
(purchased Quantity - Sold Quantity) as stock
```

So, it is can not be used in where clause.

I posted this question before, but it was closed. I searched a lot of, But I did not find any helpful in my case.

Some one asked to this by two queries, But, rather then two queries It is good practice to do by a PHP loop, since it will not have more than 5 records. But I would like to do in one query. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can run such a query for group_id 1 for many groupy you have to adept

If you have multiple Min values per group and you onoly want one row,. you to add a ROW_NUMBER to the result and select pnly the forst

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tables
>     (`group_id` int, `product_id` int, `product_name` varchar(9), `price` int, `stock` int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tables
>     (`group_id`, `product_id`, `product_name`, `price`, `stock`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 101, 'Product 1', 120, 200),
>     (1, 102, 'Product 2', 140, 90),
>     (1, 103, 'Product 3', 90, 300),
>     (2, 104, 'Product 4', 30, 45)
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `product_name`
> ,(SELECT SUM(`price`) FROM tables WHERE `group_id` = 1) sumprice 
> ,(SELECT MIN(`stock`) FROM tables WHERE `group_id` = 1) MINstock 
> FROM tables WHERE `stock` = (SELECT MIN(`stock`) FROM tables WHERE `group_id` = 1) AND `group_id` = 1
> ```
>
> ```
> product_name | sumprice | MINstock
> :----------- | -------: | -------:
> Product 2    |      350 |       90
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `product_name`
> ,(SELECT SUM(`price`) FROM tables WHERE `group_id` =  t1.`group_id`) sumprice 
> ,(SELECT MIN(`stock`) FROM tables WHERE `group_id` =  t1.`group_id`) MINstock 
> FROM tables t1 WHERE (`group_id`,`stock`) = (SELECT `group_id`,MIN(`stock`) FROM tables WHERE `group_id` = t1.`group_id`)
> ```
>
> ```
> product_name | sumprice | MINstock
> :----------- | -------: | -------:
> Product 2    |      350 |       90
> Product 4    |       30 |       45
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `product_name`,t2.sumprice,  t1.`stock`
> FROM tables t1 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `group_id`, MIN(`stock`) minstock, SUM(`price`) sumprice FROM tables GROUP BY `group_id`) t2
> ON t1.`group_id` = t2.`group_id` AND t1.`stock`= t2.minstock
> WHERE t1.`group_id`= 1
> ```
>
> ```
> product_name | sumprice | stock
> :----------- | -------: | ----:
> Product 2    |      350 |    90
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3a17656e4ae222de07e326882b568a6)*

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. The stock is calculating by a big MySQL function which already taking 0.06 s. But in your solution, I have to use the function two times. Is it possible to do this by calling the function one time?

Comment: And another things, since the stock is a calculated value and no such (stock) column is exited on the table, how will it be used on where clause?

Comment: you ask for a solution and then ask , two aggreation function and a join will cost time, add index on group_id